# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' error happens

Tags: mysql, django

When I run python manage.py migrate in my Django app, error happens like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 862, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._process_auth(plugin_name, auth_packet)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 933, in _process_auth
    pkt = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I wrote `mysql -u root`,ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) error happens and when I run service `mysqld start`,Failed to start mysqld.service: Access denied error happens.Furthermore,when I run `service mysql stop`,Failed to stop mysql.service: Access denied error happen.I add sudo to each command, but same error happens.I really cannot understand why authentication error happens.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-p` flag also in command in newer MySQL versions:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

then enter the password and you will be able to login.

> Now you can create a new user as `admin` as you are using it with password and other permissions and can use in **settings.py** file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be `root` user to run `service mysqld start` or `service mysqld start`.